# How to use the input gradients as variables within a custom loss function in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, gradient, loss-function, derivative

I am using the input gradient as feature important and want to compare the feature importance of a train datapoint with the human annotated feature importance. I would like to make this comparison differentiable such that it can be learned through backpropagation. For that, I am writing a custom loss function that in addition to the regular loss (e.g. m.s.e. on the prediction vs true labels) also checks whether the input gradient is correct (e.g. m.s.e. of the input gradient vs the human annotated feature importance).

With the following code I am able to get the input gradient:

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

def normalize(x):
    # utility function to normalize a tensor by its L2 norm
    return x / (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(x))) + 1e-5)

# Amount of training samples
N = 1000
input_dim = 10

# Generate training set make the 1st and 2nd feature same as the target feature
X = np.random.standard_normal(size=(N, input_dim))
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(N, 1))
X[:, 1] = y[:, 0]
X[:, 2] = y[:, 0]

# Create simple model
inputs = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
x = Dense(10, name="dense1")(inputs)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(input=[inputs], output=output)

# Compile and fit model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mse", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([X], y, epochs=100, batch_size=64)

# Get function to get input gradients
gradients = K.gradients(model.output, model.input)[0]
gradient_function = K.function([model.input], [normalize(gradients)])

# Get input gradient values of the training-set
grads_val = gradient_function([X])[0]
print(grads_val[:2])
```

This prints the following (you can see that the 1st and the 2nd features have the highest importance):

```
[[ 1.2629046e-02  2.2765596e+00  2.1479919e+00  2.1558853e-02
   4.5277486e-03  2.9851785e-03  9.5279224e-04 -1.0903150e-02
  -1.2230731e-02  2.1960819e-02]
 [ 1.1318034e-02  2.0402350e+00  1.9250139e+00  1.9320872e-02
   4.0577268e-03  2.6752844e-03  8.5390132e-04 -9.7713526e-03
  -1.0961102e-02  1.9681118e-02]]
```

How can I write a custom loss function in which the input gradients are differentiable?
I started with the following loss function.

```
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error
def custom_loss():
    # human annotated feature importance
    # Let's say that it says to only look at the second feature
    human_feature_importance = []
    for i in range(N):
        human_feature_importance.append([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])


    def loss(y_true, y_pred):

        # Get regular loss
        regular_loss_value = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

        # Somehow get the input gradient of each training sample as a tensor
        # It should be differential w.r.t. all of the weights
        gradients = ??
        feature_importance_loss_value = mean_squared_error(gradients, human_feature_importance)

        # Combine the both losses
        return regular_loss_value + feature_importance_loss_value
    return loss
```

I also found an implementation in tensorflow to make the input gradient differentialble: https://github.com/dtak/rrr/blob/master/rrr/tensorflow_perceptron.py#L18